# Assigning AVAsset from NSData

Tags: ios, avfoundation

Can I initialise `AVAsset` from `NSData`.. I know i can initialise `AVData` from url using the function like

```
 [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
```

Can any one suggest me a similar way of assigning `AVAsset` directly from `NSData`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, no. `AVAsset` represents items in the (internal) media library of a device, so initializing it using your custom data wouldn't make much sense. Perhaps it's worth mentioning that this class doesn't have a public initializer for `NSData`.

I suspect that you should most probably need to redesign your code logic if you need this.

Comment: I am actually downloading few audio file from internent and then using AVMutableComposition to merge all of them together. So i need to create AVAsset for each file. Can you please suggest a better way

Comment: @user1495306 why do you **need** to create an asset for them?

Comment: for creating AVMutableComposition

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is incorrect.

It is possible to create an `AVAsset` from an `NSData` via an `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` implementation.

Specifically implement:

```
func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool
```

It must:

1. fill in the loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest correctly.  Hint, use `loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest.contentType = AVFileType.mycontenttype.rawValue`
2. respond with data correctly

I'll post some code later, but you can google "AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate github" for examples

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate solution the way I solved it. Indirectly I initialised by writing/saving NSData to local directory first and then initialise AVAsset from that filepath.

```
AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:locationUrl]];
```

You can try writing your nsdata to filepath first then initialising from that path to AVAsset.

```
[videoData writeToFile: locationUrl atomically:YES];
```

Just make sure that file location URL is correct and also test confirm if data is being saved to that file path if anything error happens when loading back. Lastly don't forget to clean up your files if you no longer need them.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the difference of NSData vs. Data,

but I use a subclass AVDataAsset that installed a AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate to solve the problem like @iamacomputer suggested like below:

```
class AVDataAsset: AVURLAsset,  AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate {
    private let myUrl:   URL
    private var mediaData = Data()
    
    init(url: URL,data: Data?) {
        myUrl = url
        let retURL: URL
        if let data {
            mediaData = data
            guard var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) else {
                fatalError()
            }
            components.scheme = (components.scheme ?? "") + "SchemeSuffix"
            guard let newURL = components.url else {
                fatalError()
            }
            retURL = newURL
        } else {
            retURL = url
        }
        super.init(url:   retURL, options: nil)
        self.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
//        print("Size: \(mediaData.count)")
    }
    func resourceLoader(_ resourceLoader: AVAssetResourceLoader, shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource loadingRequest: AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest) -> Bool {
        let request = loadingRequest
        if let ri = request.contentInformationRequest  {
            ri.isByteRangeAccessSupported = true
            ri.contentType = "video/quicktime"
            ri.contentLength = Int64(mediaData.count)
        }
        if let dataRequest = request.dataRequest {
            let downloadedData          = self.mediaData
            let downloadedDataLength    = Int64(downloadedData.count)
            let requestCurrentOffset    = dataRequest.currentOffset
            let requestRequestedOffset  = dataRequest.requestedOffset
            let requestRequestedLength  = Int64(dataRequest.requestedLength)
            let downloadedUnreadDataLength  = downloadedDataLength - requestCurrentOffset
            let requestUnreadDataLength     = requestRequestedOffset + requestRequestedLength - requestCurrentOffset
            let respondDataLength           = min(requestUnreadDataLength, downloadedUnreadDataLength)
            
            dataRequest.respond(with: downloadedData.subdata(in:
                                                                Range(NSMakeRange(Int(requestCurrentOffset), Int(respondDataLength)))!))
        }
        request.finishLoading()
        
        return true
        
    }
}

let url = URL(string: "file:///Users/thilo/Desktop/Input/IMG_0128%20copy.MOV")!

guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
    else { fatalError() }

let dataAsset = AVDataAsset(url: url, data: data)
Task{
    let asset = dataAsset
    if let tracks = try? await asset.load(.tracks),
       let frameRate = try? await tracks[0].load(.minFrameDuration),
       let duration = try? await asset.load(.duration) {
        print("frame: \(1/frameRate.seconds) Dura: \(duration.seconds)")
    }
}
        
print("Done AVDataAsset")
```

Obviously, some bits are here hardcoded and need changing but the principle should be clear.

It's also worth noting, that the URL scheme must not be a known scheme for the delegate to be called ( +SchemeSuffix does it )